# iTunes connect mac build uploaded from iTunes doesn't have an icon

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store, app-store-connect, mac-app-store

I've archived and validated my app via Xcode, and when I submit it the app looks like this:
[image]

After submitting it to iTunes connect, the build shows up but it doesn't have an app icon, and as a result the app page doesn't have an icon either:

[image]

Why is this happening? And what is this "A" folder in my build? I have checked my Xcode project folder and no such folder or diretctory exists

Comment: I have the same problem. For me, I was replacing an icon with an updated icon. Eventually, the app page displayed the new icon once it was approved a week later by Apple, but it never showed up next to the build. It also appeared in the store correctly and in Mac OS after downloading the app from the App Store.  IOW, I don't think it's a real problem, just a bug in the new iTunes Connect site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shows up after the version is submitted for review.